# Mysql- How to combine all values from one columns with all values from another column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `t(C1,C2)` , and I want to combine all values from `C1` with all values from column `C2`.
For example,

```
C1 | C2
a  | b
c  | d
e  | f
```

what I want is

```
C1 | C2
a  | b
a  | d
a  | f
c  | b
c  | d
c  | f
e  | b
e  | d
e  | f
```

How should write the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a cross self join:

```
SELECT t1.C1, t2.C2
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
ORDER BY t1.C1, t2.C2;
```

Note that in MySQL an inner join without an on clause defaults to behaving like a cross join.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

To be able to combine two tables use INNER JOIN. Check this [INNER JOIN Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1394b/6) running example I wrote it shows how you can do this.